# How to prepend (or append) all lines containing the word under cursor with some text?

Tags: vim

I have, e.g., the following lines :

```
I live in Paris 
You live in Montreal and New-York
She lives in Bangor
He lives in Paris and in New-York
```

I would like to prepend all lines containing some pattern (e.g. Paris) with some text, for example "-> " so as to have :

```
-> I live in Paris
You live in Montreal and New-York
She lives in Bangor
-> He lives in Paris and in New-York
```

I know how to do it with a g command :

```
:g/Paris/s/^/->
```

but I would like to simply put the cursor on Paris and have the same result.

I suppose I must create a mapping in my .vimrc, such as :

```
:nnoremap <leader>s :g/<cword>/s/^/->
```

Of course, this does not work. How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following mapping.

```
nnoremap <leader>s :let @/=expand('<cword>') <bar> g//s/^/-> /<CR>
```

It sets the search register to the word under the cursor the calls the global command. If you don't specify the pattern the last search pattern will be used which in this case will the word under the cursor.

---

Another way if you were to do this manually could be to hit `*` to set the search register to the word under the cursor. Then do the global command without specifying the pattern.

---

From @PeterRincker: You can also use `<c-r><c-w>` to insert the current word when you are in command line mode. This reduces the mapping to

```
nnoremap <leader>s :g/<c-r><c-w>/s/^/-> /<CR>
```

Comment: You can also use `<c-r><c-w>` to insert the current word.

Comment: @PeterRincker Nice didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like this, I use macros.  With the cursor on the "P" on the first "Paris":

`ywqq^i-> [ESC]nnq`

Translation:

- `yw` yank word into search register
- `qq` start recording macro called 'q'
- `^`  goto beginning of line
- `i`  insert
- '-> ' text to insert
- `[ESC]` back to command mode
- `nn`  jump forward two "Paris"'s
- `q` stop recording

Now your are positioned at the second "Paris".  Hold down the shift key and hit `@q` repeatedly until you have tagged all instances of Paris.

Once I started getting into the habit of using macros, my whole world changed.  They are very useful.

Also, this way, you won't have to clutter your vimrc with remaps, and you won't have to edit your vimrc when you decide to change "-> " to something else.

Comment: I use macros, too, but in this case, I prefer @FDinoff's solution which allows me to do the job in one shot. Thank you for your answer, anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

This is an easy one:

```
:g;Paris;s;^;-> ;g
```

Where:

```
:g    - global search
Paris - only for lines that have pattern Paris
s     - substiture
;     - field separator
^     - match beginning of line.
->    - replacement pattern
g     - all occurrences
```